# Prevent auto-layout of Graph[] objects in Mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Some types of objects have special input/output formatting in Mathematica.  This includes `Graphics`, raster images, and, as of Mathematica 8, graphs (`Graph[]`).  Unfortunately large graphs may take a very long time to visualize, much longer than most other operations I'm doing on them during interactive work.

How can I prevent auto-layout of `Graph[]` objects in StandardForm and TraditionalForm, and have them displayed as e.g. `-Graph-`, preferably preserving the interpretability of the output (perhaps using `Interpretation`?).  I think this will involve changing `Format` and/or `MakeBoxes` in some way, but I was unsuccessful in getting this to work.

I would like to do this in a reversible way, and preferably define a function that will return the original interactive graph display when applied to a `Graph` object (not the same as `GraphPlot`, which is not interactive).

On a related note, is there a way to retrieve Format/MakeBoxes definitions associated with certain symbols?  `FormatValues` is one relevant function, but it is empty for `Graph`.

**Sample session:**

```
In[1]:= Graph[{1->2, 2->3, 3->1}]
Out[1]= -Graph-

In[2]:= interactiveGraphPlot[%] (* note that % works *)
Out[2]= (the usual interactive graph plot should be shown here)
```

Comment: Szabolcs, please try my `$PrePrint` version and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I do not have Mathematica 8 to try this in, one possibility is to use this construct:

```
Unprotect[Graph]

MakeBoxes[g_Graph, StandardForm] /; TrueQ[$short] ^:= 
 ToBoxes@Interpretation[Skeleton["Graph"], g]

$short = True;
```

Afterward, a `Graph` object should display in Skeleton form, and setting `$short = False` should restore default behavior.

Hopefully this works to automate the switching:

```
interactiveGraphPlot[g_Graph] := Block[{$short}, Print[g]]
```

---

Mark's concern about modifying `Graph` caused me to consider the option of using `$PrePrint`.  I think this should also prevent the slow layout step from taking place.  It may be more desirable, assuming you are not already using `$PrePrint` for something else.

```
$PrePrint = 
  If[TrueQ[$short], # /. _Graph -> Skeleton["Graph"], #] &;

$short = True
```

Also conveniently, at least with `Graphics` (again I cannot test with `Graph` in v7) you can get the graphic with simply `Print`.  Here, shown with Graphics:

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]

(*  Out =  <<"Graphics">>  *)
```

Then

```
Print[g]
```

[image]

I left the `$short` test in place for easy switching via a global symbol, but one could leave it out and use:

```
    $PrePrint = # /. _Graph -> Skeleton["Graph"] &;
```

And then use `$PrePrint = .` to reset the default functionality.

Comment: It seems to work.  `interactiveGraphPlot` gives the original, but using the interactive features reverts it to the <<Graph>> form.  (Actually this part wasn't so important anyway.)  I should learn how `Format` and `MakeBoxes` work, and the difference between them (and also `ToBoxes`).  E.g. why is that the unmodified `MakeBoxes` does NOT return an interactive object, `ToBoxes` does, yet one needs to modify `MakeBoxes` here?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you said, but `ToBoxes` in needed because the output of `MakeBoxes` is, expectably, supposed to be Boxes; leaving it out will result in an error.  MakeBoxes by default is doing (something like) ToBoxes unless you give it special rules, like this one.

Comment: I guess I don't get it. Is it truly worth calling `Unprotect` on a built in command so that the output of `Graph` becomes `-Graph-`? I do agree that output format of a graph as an image is odd, perhaps even unfortunate. The question is, what is the proper way to deal with it? It seems to me that simple suppression of the output should be the recommended approach.

Comment: @Mark, suppressing output is the standard way to do this since version 6, and I agree that it is usually best.  However, sometimes the direct graphics formatting gets in the way.  There are times, if `g` is a `Graphics` object, and I have a expression like `{1, 2, p, 3}` I would rather see `{1, 2, -Graphic-, 3}` than a list with an actual graphic embedded in it, especially when it comes at the cost of slow display.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard - Good point! I am typically *very* cautious when using `Unprotect`. I share notebooks with a lot of people - students and colleagues alike. In my experience, any customization that I do is likely to confuse others and will typically not be very robust. That is the source of my reticence.

Comment: @Mark Good point yourself.  Would modifying `$PrePrint` be more comfortable?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you might be interested in this: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/a864bf7059938c55#   I saw this discussed many years ago on MathGroup, but I can't find that discussion now.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you, that **is** interesting.  But does it relate to this answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GraphLayout` option of `Graph` as well as graph-constructors to suppress the rendering.  A graph can still be visualized with `GraphPlot`. Try the following

```
{gr1, gr2, gr3} = {RandomGraph[{100, 120}, GraphLayout -> None], 
  PetersenGraph[10, 3, GraphLayout -> None], 
  Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, GraphLayout -> None]}
```

[image]

In order to make working easier, you can use `SetOptions` to set `GraphLayout` option to `None` for all graph constructors you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply suppressing the output? I don't think that V8's `Graph` command does any layout, if you do so.  To explore this, we can generate a large list of edges and compare the timings of `graph[edges];`, `Graph[edges];`, and `GraphPlot[edges];`

```
In[23]:= SeedRandom[1];
edges = Union[Rule @@@ (Sort /@ 
      RandomInteger[{1, 5000}, {50000, 2}])];

In[25]:= t = AbsoluteTime[];
graph[edges];

In[27]:= AbsoluteTime[] - t

Out[27]= 0.029354

In[28]:= t = AbsoluteTime[];
Graph[edges];

In[30]:= AbsoluteTime[] - t

Out[30]= 0.080434

In[31]:= t = AbsoluteTime[];
GraphPlot[edges];

In[33]:= AbsoluteTime[] - t

Out[33]= 4.934918
```

The inert `graph` command is, of course, the fastest. The `Graph` command takes much longer, but no where near as long as the `GraphPlot` command. Thus, it seems to me that `Graph` is not, in fact, computing the layout, as `GraphPlot` does.

The logical question is, what is `Graph` spending it's time on.  Let's examine the `InputForm` of `Graph` output in a simple case:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 4}] // InputForm

Out[123]//InputForm=
    Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 
      {DirectedEdge[1, 2], 
       DirectedEdge[2, 3], 
       DirectedEdge[3, 1], 
       DirectedEdge[1, 4]}]
```

Note that the vertices of the graph have been determined and I think this is what `Graph` is doing. In fact, the amount of time it took to compute `Graph[edges]` in the first example, comparable to the fastest way that I can think to do this:

```
Union[Sequence @@@ edges]; // Timing
```

This took 0.087045 seconds.

Comment: `Graph` itself does not do the layout, its interactive output does.  It's just like waiting for graphics to be rendered.  Therefore you can't even measure this time using either `Timing` or `AbsoluteTiming`.  Yes, I can suppress the output, but the whole point is that I don't really want to bother doing that, and I will forget it occasionally anyway:  I don't want to be punished for forgetting to suppress the output by having to wait for half a minute or more.

Comment: In fact now I started to wonder whether it's the layout algorithm or the graphics rendering that takes so long to complete...

Comment: I've edited my example to properly measure the time, even though there's some front end stuff going on that I had supposed to be negligible.  I think the timings still support my conclusions. I agree that the graphics rendering is likely to be more expensive than the vertex layout.